# Why do 2 histograms overlap in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, random, histogram, subplot

In this python script is an attempt to create two histogram in one figure but the second histogram overlaps the first one

```
from random import randrange
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50,50))
ids =  [str(randrange(10000, 99999)) for i in range(1000)]
ids2 = [str(randrange(10000, 99999)) for i in range(1000)]
def fun1():
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    n, bins, patches = ax.hist(x=ids, bins=range(500))
    ax.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.6)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=3.0, w_pad=2.0, h_pad=2.0)

def fun2():
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
    n, bins, patches = ax2.hist(x=ids2, bins=range(500))
    ax2.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.6)
  
fun1()
fun2()
```

Although I used `tight_layout` this does not help with the overlapping of the two histograms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the subplots in this order

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
```

What you meant should be this

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)
```

`(2, 1)` will arrange the plots in 2 rows and 1 column, then the third parameter is to specify subplots `1` and `2`

[image]

If you specify `(1, 2)` there will be 1 row and 2 columns

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
```

[image]